# Angular-cli - Test Service

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I'm using the angular-cli and have tried to get into the habbit of testing my services, but I can't seem to inject the service into the test here's my situation:

**Angular2 Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
}
```

**Karma Test - V1.3.0**

Is this the correct syntax? It seems it's changed throughout the initial release of angular2.

```
describe('Tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => [
    {provide: AppService, useClass: AppService}
  ]);

  it('should create an instance', inject([AppService], (service: AppService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Is this the correct syntax? It seems it's changed throughout the initial release of angular2.

**Test Error**

```
Tests should create an instance FAILED
    Error: No provider for AppService!
```

**My Configuration**

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21
node: 6.5.0
os: win32 x64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to inject it, you still need to use the `TestBed` to configure the Angular test environment

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [ {provide: AppService, useClass: AppService} ]
}));
```

*Note:** If the service doesn't have any other dependencies, you might just want to forget the Angular configuration, and just do an isolated test by instantiating the service yourself.

```
let service = new AppService();
```

**See also:**

- [Angular Testings docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) for more details on testing with the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it working! Nice, I forgot how detailed the angular2 documentation is now. It seems to work only with `useValue:` though, any ideas why that works?

Comment: Huh? Do you mean when you do `new AppService()`. If so, what I mean by that part is that you should just forget the whole TestBed configuration and just create a new instance yourself for the tests. Otherwise, the first code works fine as is, though it could be simplified to just `providers: [ AppService ]`

Comment: And yes `useValue` is when you want to use your own created instance. `useClass` is only when you want Angular to create it

Comment: Thanks again, the simplified version you mentioned above is good enough to get me started. Later on I'll try the more complicated tests, using stubs etc.